# Rails - show joins table attribute in partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have two models:

1. **Routes** has_many :details
2. **Detail** belongs_to :route

In the Route model I defined the following scopes:

```
scope :origin_city_name, -> (origin) { where origin_city_name: origin }
scope :destination_city_name, -> (destination) { where destination_city_name: destination }
```

In **routes_controller.rb** I have a custom action defined as follow:

```
def getstring
  ...
  @routes = Route.origin_city_name(from)
            .destination_city_name(to)
            .joins(:details)
            .order('details.departure ASC')
end
```

In the **routes/getstring.html.erb** view I have the following:

```
<%= render @routes %>
```

And then in the **routes/_route.html.erb** partial:

```
<%= route.origin_station_name %>
<%= route.destination_station_name %>
<%= route.price %>
```

where `price` is an attribute of Detail.

When I run the server I get the following error:

> undefined method `price' for # Route:0x00000004054598

Also, if I call route.inspect in the _route partial I get a "normal" Route object and not an object of the join table.

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: As `Route` `has_many` `Details`, which ones' price do you want to display?

Comment: actually, all of them. I thought that the combo <%= render @routes %> in the view and route.attribute in the partial was enough to iterate on the collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def getstring
  ...
  @routes = Route.origin_city_name(from)
            .destination_city_name(to)
            .joins(:details)
            .select("routes.*, details.price AS price")
            .order('details.departure ASC')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As `Route` `has_many` `Details`, and `price` is a `Detail`'s model attribute, you should do the following to iterate through all of them:

```
<% route.details.each do |detail| %>
  <%=detail.price%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks, your solution is good as well, but I prefer the flexibility given by SQL query